# VBScript runtime error '800a0005'

Tags: vbscript

Not sure why I am getting this error for invalid procedure call for my **right** call.

Here is my line of code:

lcase(right(trim(RS2.Fields("First_Name")),len(RS2.Fields("Last_Name"))-1))

I can trim everything off and leave just the **right** function and it will not run as long as I have the length calculation in there. If I make it a simple integer it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `len(RS2.Fields("Last_Name"))` won't be 0, so the second parameter can't become -1. Either prepend an If clause or use a Max()-function that clips values < 0.

Evidence:

```
>> sLN = ""
>> s = Right("pipapo", Len(sLN) - 1)
>>
Error Number:       5
Error Description:  Invalid procedure call or argument
```